# Create folders in wwwroot on startup in NetCore

Tags: asp.net-core, c#-4.0, wwwroot

Is there a way to create folders in `wwwroot` when the application startup?
Perhaps in the `startup.cs` class?

I know how to create folders in `wwwroot`  in controller action methods. I do not want this.

This is what I would like:

- I have a List of Objects: `List<Organization> Organizations`
- `foreach (Organization in Organization)`  I want a folder with the `Organization.Name`  created in the `wwwroot` folder
- I would like it to be created at the moment the application is launched

Thanks in advance you for any help

Comment: Hi @ZAD, any updates about this case? Does the solution(s) that we shared help achieve the requirement?

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following

**but please note that you have duplicate variable names in your foreach**

```
var rootFolder=Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(),"wwwroot");
foreach (org in Organizations){
    var orgFolderPath=Path.Combine(rootfolder,org.Name);
    if(!Directory.Exists(orgFolderPath){
        Directory.CreateDirectory(orgFolderPath);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to create folders in wwwroot when the application startup? Perhaps in the startup.cs class?

To achieve the requirement, you can try to inject [`IHostApplicationLifetime`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.ihostapplicationlifetime?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0) into `Configure()` method and write the callback for `ApplicationStarted`, then you can create folder(s) based on `List<Organization> Organizations`.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, IHostApplicationLifetime lifetime)
{
    //...
    //your code here

    lifetime.ApplicationStarted.Register(OnApplicationStartedAsync(env).Wait);

    //...
}

private async Task<Action> OnApplicationStartedAsync(IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    foreach (var org in Organizations)
    {
        var path = Path.Combine(env.WebRootPath, $"{org.Name}");

        if (!Directory.Exists(path))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
        }
    }
           

    return null;
}
```